# FileUpload control retrieve null value in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I've a `fileupload` control and I want to get `filename` in `codebehind`. I'm using `editindex` event when I choose file and press `editindex` button then I'm getting `null` value of `fileupload`.
Here is my `aspx` code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="comp_gr" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="comp_gr_RowEditing">
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ButtonType="Button"  EditText="Complete Task"  ControlStyle-BorderColor="White" ControlStyle-BorderStyle="Double" ControlStyle-BackColor="#990000" />
</Columns
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attach Document">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:FileUpload  ForeColor="Black" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my `codebehind`

```
protected void comp_gr_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
FileUpload file = (FileUpload)comp_gr.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("FileUpload1");
string f = file.FileName.ToString();
}
```

But I'm getting always `null` value in `f`.

Answer (score 0):

you should place your FileUpload control in `<EditItemTemplate>` field instead of `<ItemTemplate>`.

If you don't know about it kindly google about it.

Comment: what do you mean?I can't understand

Comment: Check this link
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

Comment: If i put this `fileupload` control in inside the `<EditItemTemplate>` then `fileupload` control vanished when `gridview` display.Not `fileupload` show after doing this

Comment: when gridview is in view mode it will show the items that are placed in <ItemTemplate> and when you click edit button in gridview at that time the row will be in edit mode and will show the controls placed in <EditItemTemplate>. so if you want to view it when gridview loads you should also put fileupload control in <ItemTemplate>. Then after it will be visible in both modes.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the file upload control in OnRowEdit event of the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Grid (and with the the FileUpload control) in an UpdatePanel? If so, that's where your problem lies. Either remove the updatepanel or set the save button or whatever is causing the postback to be a PostBack control instead of an async postback control.